# What is the max number of rows one should pull at once from a database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a process that iterates through thousands of database tables and aggregates data, and I want to set a threshold limit `N` where if the row count is larger than N my process will dump the data to a file.

I'm wondering what would be a good limit for N?

Comment: There seem to be some crucial but unwritten assumptions in your question. For example, why do you think dumping data to a file would be any more effective than another means of extracting the data from the database? Whatever your reasons might be for cutting over to a file dump, the most effective way to determine the best value of N is almost certainly trial and error.

Comment: There are no appreciable logical limits .. exist only in memory-related limits (and your patience eg: the waiting time)

Comment: That is what was recommended by our DBA.  The id primary key can range from 1 to over a trillion with huge gaps in between so it's impossible to pull in increments of N rows.  And when I do an ORDER BY/LIMIT combo and iterate through that way it brings our dB to its knees.

Comment: thousands of tables? seriously?

Comment: 6,800 to be exact.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should have the database do all the aggregation and joining necessary rather than doing it in your application. That would just be a waste of time and resources.

Second, to process large amounts of data, it is better to [open a cursor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html) for the query result and [iterate through that](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-fetch.html) than to write it all to a temporary file and process that.

It is hard to give any more detailed advice with so little knowledge of your use case.